# Phonegap/Cordova 3.4 clean build gets apple mach- linker error

Tags: cordova

I tried several options on stackoverflow. But none of them seem to work.

My project is just a clean phonegap build.

I just updated phonegap from 3.3 to 3.4 and i get these messages:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zsn21n5sakp0d3/Screenshot%202014-03-18%2012.50.03.png

Comment: Is this in Xcode? when you try to build?

Comment: i build via command line: cordova build ios, then i start the app via xcode

Comment: When you say start the app... you open your project in Xcode and run it in a simulator?

Comment: I just remember that my employer renewed the apple dev account. Could it have something to do with this?

Comment: First i build the app via command line, Then select my device(iPhone 5s) and press start

Comment: Does it build ok when running on the ios simulator?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49943/discussion-between-mulhoon-and-codingbear)

Comment: Yes, the build is ok on the simulator.

Comment: Did you really try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311075/after-update-to-xcode-5-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7-or-armv

Comment: Setting Build Active Architecture Only to NO???

Comment: @GenieWanted No this doesn't help either

Comment: So no one can helpe me out here? It says: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/beer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialDeal-fkyjnuzwsqnmsadubagqblberdhv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/beer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialDeal-fkyjnuzwsqnmsadubagqblberdhv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a (2 slices)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i found the solution:

1. Select your Project icon
2. Choose Build Settings.
3. For "Architectures", select $ARCHS_STANDARD - Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
4. For "Valid Architectures", add "arm64"
5. Select your CordovaLib.xcodeproj icon
6. In the Build Settings for the Project (not Target), delete the conditional architecture settings (this is any value under "Release" or "Debug" - hover to see the minus sign)
7. For "Architectures", select $ARCHS_STANDARD - Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
8. For "Valid Architectures", add "arm64"
9. Goto 6, but now do it for "Target"

[source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223)

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

In Xcode, click your project and go to **Build Settings > Architectures > Build Active Architecture Only** and set both Debug and Release to **Yes**.

Your error seems similar to something that happened to me.

More here...
[Phonegap/Cordova Build error - Apple Mach-O Linker Error: no such file or directory: libCordova.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621421/phonegap-cordova-build-error-apple-mach-o-linker-error-no-such-file-or-direct/12622094#12622094)

Comment: It's already on YES. I really tried so much answers on stack overflow.

Comment: This helped for me, but does this mean that the resulting build won't run on some devices?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the *Build Settings > Architectures > Build Active Architecture Only* settings are equal for both the CordovaLib project and your app's project. If the CordovaLib is only built for the active architecture, you will get a linker error when XCode tries to build the rest of the project for other architectures.

Answer (score 0):

**Build Settings** > **Architectures**

[image]