# phonegap app crashes after installing plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

After the fix i found for my previous issue: [phonegap-cordova-3-4-clean-build-gets-apple-mach-linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478585/phonegap-cordova-3-4-clean-build-gets-apple-mach-linker-error)

So now, if I make a blank project

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova build ios
```

Now I need to do follow these instructions [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478585/phonegap-cordova-3-4-clean-build-gets-apple-mach-linker-error)
After that everything works fine.

BUT now I'm gonna install an plugin (doesn't matter what plugin).
For now i choose the logger (org.apache.cordova.console)

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

Now if i build and run the app. It crashes on startup.
see: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx7d8y0ukp5iqu8/Screenshot%202014-03-19%2015.08.47.png)

I enabled on Zombie Objects in xcode.

Even if I install previous versions of phonegap(cordova). I still need to do all these steps. Before I just create, add platform, build and run and it was done.

Nothing is working anymore, please helpe me out here. It's really annoying.

EDIT: If i comment the line console.log('Received Event: ' + id); in js/index.js the app will start, but if I call console.log it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

objc_msgSend causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS with plugins on arm64

So i found why this happened:

I needed to replace in the fie ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m

```
objc_msgSend(obj, normalSelector, command);
```

in

```
((void (*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend)(obj, normalSelector, command);
```

now everything works fine again.

[source](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=blobdiff;f=CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m;h=1eddfe37ee699289701cd4caaf68486607010501;hp=902dfa0227f1358296d2218fa0e6d5cc2a882ea6;hb=82ce4f2;hpb=7da5f2df3417de68a1b540bc00c11a95ce3dc7d6)

Answer (score 0):

I found something. If I build for ios. the js (console-via-logger.js) is doing the id wrong
[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj65f0rz8m5iqfo/Screenshot%202014-03-19%2016.03.04.png)

If I change

```
cordova.define("org.apache.cordova.console.console", function(require, exports, module) { /*
```

to

```
cordova.define("org.apache.cordova.console", function(require, exports, module) { /*
```

it works.

Has this something todo with me or cordova?

cordova -v: 3.4.0-0.1.3
npm -v: 1.4.5